# How to use Ansible to import GPG key in RHEL 8

Tags: ansible, gnupg

Using Ansible, how do I import a GPG key into RHEL 8?

Using the Ansible `rpm_key` module I am attempting to import the FireEye GPG key found at https://www.fireeye.com/company/security/keys.html  This is my Ansible code:

```
- name: Import the FireEye GPG Key from a file
  rpm_key:
    state: present
    key: /tmp/buildfiles/antivirus/fireeye-key.gpg

- name: Install FireEye Agent package
  yum:
    name: /tmp/buildfiles/antivirus/fireeye/xagt-34.28.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
    state: present
```

I copied the GPG key and saved it in fireeye-key.gpg.  With a direct copy I get this error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to validate GPG signature for xagt-33.46.0-1.el7.x86_64"}
```

My next try was to remove the blank lines found in the second and second last line of the GPG key.  However, that produces this error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created\ngpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created\ngpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...\ngpg: invalid armor header: mQINBFu7nVUBEADC6YSWxdVWbh3Aeh+2vkJpFeRe8hnvx38tUcbYqO9sm3y/NDTA\\n\ngpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created\n"}
```

Initially the `Import the FireEye GPG Key from a file` task was absent and the `Install FireEye Agent package` task produced this error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to validate GPG signature for xagt-34.28.6-1.el7.x86_64"}
```

It was due to this error that I added the `Import the FireEye GPG Key from a file` task using `rpm_key'.

Comment: The error is complaining about the format of `/tmp/buildfiles/antivirus/fireeye-key.gpg`. Where does that file come from? Have you verified that it contains a valid GPG key?

Comment: It comes from https://www.fireeye.com/company/security/keys.html  which has the GPG and S/MIME keys.  I copied the GPG key and saved it in fireeye-key.gpg

Answer (score 2):

I think the format of the key is wrong, through no fault of your own. If you copy-and-paste the key from that web page, you end up with:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQINBFu7nVUBEADC6YSWxdVWbh3Aeh+2vkJpFeRe8hnvx38tUcbYqO9sm3y/NDTA
0fysb6ZBO/VYUQcQ4zRTGfytGzLmNPWrwBxcmEnLq5F/SQ1mOXxdjf2fIOhErVmD
kliJ96mS/iYV6Z700byMEAciZra5zyOvYSCAncrpDrVyk0mKpE9AZcSeBSUkamCB
...
TQz8S/+M2MtLTCqNppeWwWlTQlYKajTuLexiIfNEJeutzIkAdWowolVFqZhlkB+a
67fAMXnNqH87ipGypf/db3kspgs=
=LMuX

-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

If you attempt to import that key, it fails:

```
# rpm --import fireeye.key
error: fireeye.key: key 1 not an armored public key.
```

If you edit the file to remove the blank line before the `-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK` line, so that you have:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

mQINBFu7nVUBEADC6YSWxdVWbh3Aeh+2vkJpFeRe8hnvx38tUcbYqO9sm3y/NDTA
0fysb6ZBO/VYUQcQ4zRTGfytGzLmNPWrwBxcmEnLq5F/SQ1mOXxdjf2fIOhErVmD
kliJ96mS/iYV6Z700byMEAciZra5zyOvYSCAncrpDrVyk0mKpE9AZcSeBSUkamCB
...
TQz8S/+M2MtLTCqNppeWwWlTQlYKajTuLexiIfNEJeutzIkAdWowolVFqZhlkB+a
67fAMXnNqH87ipGypf/db3kspgs=
=LMuX
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Then it imports successfully. I believe this will fix the errors
you're seeing with Ansible.

Comment: Thanks, that got me one step further to a new error.  Now the `Import the FireEye GPG Key from a file` task succeeds, but the next task, `Install FireEye Agent package` fails with this error: `Failed to validate GPG signature for xagt-34.28.6-1.el7.x86_64`